# Why do both trig functions have the same Macluarin series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, power-series

Both the degree version and the radian version of the trig functions have the same Maclaurin series, yet they are different. How is this possible? How can two different functions have the same Maclaurin series?

Comment: Please clarify, I'm not sure what you're talking about.

Comment: They don't have the same series. Why do you think they do?

Comment: @Raskolnikov The degree version of sine is not the same as the radian version. For instance sin(pi degrees) isn't equal to sin (pi radians)

Comment: @MPW I haven't come across any source that gives two different Maclaurin series for both types of sine. They always give a single Maclaurin series for sin (x) without specifying radians or degrees.

Comment: In fact, $d(\theta) = r(\pi\theta/180)$. So you can see the sequence of successive derivatives won't agree at most points.

Comment: Almost certainly the assumption is that the angle is measured in radians for such series.

Comment: @MPW Even if you derive it yourself, you get the same series for both. For instance for sin (x): sin(0) cos(0), -sin (0) and every other derivative is identical for both degrees and radians at x= 0. So they would produce the same series.

Comment: Not so. The derivative of $\sin$ in degrees at $0$ is $\pi/180$. You may be assuming, incorrectly, that the derivative of $\sin$ is $\cos$ regardless of the unit of the variable.

Comment: If the degree version of sine is different from the radian version then obviously, $\lim_{x\to 0} \sin(x)/x$ is different in degrees. But this means the derivative is different as well.

Comment: @KevinCarlson But the derivative of the degree sine function is the cos degree function which evaluates to 0 at x= 0 degrees.

Comment: No, it's not. If $\sin^d$ is the $\sin$-in-degrees function, then $d/dx \sin^d x=d/dx \sin \pi x/180=\pi/180\cos \pi x/180=\pi/180 \cos^d x$.

Comment: Specifically, if $r$ is the "radian version" of the sine function and $d$ is the "degree version", then $$r(x)= x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\cdots $$ while $$d(x)= \frac{\pi x}{180}-\frac{\pi^3x^3}{180^3 3!}+\frac{\pi^5x^5}{180^5 5!}-\cdots $$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Practically nobody does calculus using the "degrees" version of trigonometric functions,
and this is one of the reasons why.  The function that gives the
sine of a number of radians is not the function that gives the sine of a number of degrees,
and you cannot just start taking derivatives of both functions and expecting that the
only thing you need to do to reconcile them is to use the "correct" units of input.

For clarity, I'll write 
$\sin_r(x)$ to mean "sine of the value $x$ when $x$ is given in radians," and 
$\sin_d(x)$ to mean "sine of the value $x$ when $x$ is given in degrees." 
Similarly, I'll wrote $\cos_r(x)$ and $\cos_d(x)$ to distinguish the two cosine functions.
Then
$$ \frac{d}{dx} \sin_r(x) = \cos_r(x).$$
But
$$ \frac{d}{dx} \sin_d(x) \ne \cos_d(x).$$
In fact, the two sides of that inequality are not even close, as you can easily
confirm by integrating $\cos_d(x)$ from $60$ degrees to $90$ degrees.
Since $\cos_d(x) \ge \frac 12$ over that entire range, the answer cannot be
less than $\frac 12 \cdot(90-60) = 15,$ which plainly is much greater than
the difference between $\sin_d(90)$ and $\sin_d(60).$

In fact, since  $\sin_d(x) = \sin_r\left(\frac{\pi}{180} x\right),$
we find that
$$\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{d}{dx} \sin_d(x) &=& \frac{d}{dx} \sin_r\left(\frac{\pi}{180} x\right) \\
&=& \frac{\pi}{180} \cos_r\left(\frac{\pi}{180} x\right) \\
&=& \frac{\pi}{180} \cos_d(x).
\end{eqnarray}$$
If you construct your MacLaurin series using correctly calculated derivatives,
you will find it looks much different than the usual MacLaurin series,
but you should find that your new MacLaurin series is what you would get if you were to
substitute $\frac{\pi}{180} x$ for $x$ in the usual MacLaurin series.
(There would be a lot of powers of $\pi$ and $180$ occurring in the terms of the series.)